# Not able to create the ExtractTopic Transformation in Confluent Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I was able to create the ElasticSinkConnector with ExtractTopic transformation in Confluent.Cloud platform two week ago. But, it was not available that feature now. Why did they remove that feature in Confluent.Cloud?.

Otherwise, Do we have other option available equivalent to ExtractTopic?.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're not Confluent Support. Contact them for assistance adding or supporting this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I was informed this feature was enabled but it was disabled and will have the documentation updated with details very soon.